# cellForRowAt indexPath function in swift 3 - method does not override and method from its superclass

Tags: xcode, uitableview, superclass, swift3, xcode8

I have re-typed the function, played around with the deletion of the override portion, yet still can't get the superclass error to dissipate.  Before Xcode crashed on me last night and converted to the latest swift 3 syntax, this code (albeit in prior 2.3 syntax) was fully functional.  Can't seem to catch the bug here.

```
 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return BPC.count
}

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BPCcell") as! BPC_TableCell
    cell.namelabel.text = BPC[indexPath.row].name
    cell.addresslabel.text = BPC[indexPath.row].address
    return cell
}
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "BPCsegue"
    {
        if let destViewControler = segue.destinationViewController as? BPCDetails
        {
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            destViewControler.details = BPC[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Quit Xcode and empty the DerivedData folder.

Comment: How do you know so much, matt?

Comment: I'm unbelievably old. :)